# Angular 5 wait for createEmbeddedView to render

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to render a templateRef from a component into a ng-container from another component.

The destination component receives a call to method showTemplate with the templateRef and I want to render it and after it is displayed, to make further modifications to it, i.e. to scroll to an arbitrary element from the template.

The destination component looks like this:

```
export class OverlayComponent {
  embeddedViewRef: EmbeddedViewRef<any>;
  @ViewChild('mntPageOverlayContainer', {read: ViewContainerRef}) container: ViewContainerRef;

  showTemplate(value: TemplateRef<any>, props?: OverlayProps) {
    this.embeddedViewRef = this.container.createEmbeddedView(value);

    if (props && props.onShow) {
      this.embeddedViewRef.rootNodes.forEach(element => [make modifications to it]);
    }
  }
```

The html template has these elements:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let m of months">
    <a (click)="selectMonth(m)" [ngClass]="{'selected': m === month}">{{monthNameFor(m)}}</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I want to be able to call `props.onShow(element)` AFTER the entire template was rendered so that I can make further modifications to it. Particularly, I want to scroll into view the `<li>` with css class `selected`.

But what appears to happen is that Angular calls my code after is has only added the root element of the template, not the entire subtree. Only the `<ul>` element is available, and the `<li>` elements in the template are to be rendered later on.

Comment: Look at the lifcycle hooks: https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks You should probably do what you want in `ngAfterViewChecked()`

Comment: @StephaneM Duh! Major brain fail on my part... Thank you for your help.